# way and fastest way to create internet data based android app

Tags: android, google-maps, database-design

I want programming an android application by google maps v2.
many of my map data inserted a sqlite database side of app.
but many map data i want read from internet.
data are many many text info about many map locations and them lat,long.
can i use sql server for saving data on web and read it's data in android app?
how many ways exist to create an app that it's data read from internet?
which of them is fastest way to retrieve data from internet.
i hope understand my mean.....
thanks....

Comment: It is hard to get understand your requirements.

Comment: ok. i understood it myself and point to it. excuse me truly.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i write an asp.net Web Service that return json pure string. but i used a ashx handler for return pure json string. thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any database of your choice. Later it's just the matter of creating a webservice to return the data for the Ajax requests from your app.

Comment: very thanks. why ajax? can i trust to these sent and received ajax data? my mean is security for hack data. please tell me which is the fastest way to read data from web.

Comment: Since you're working on Android Ajax is the only way to get data to your app. Use SSL for your webservice for security.

Comment: thanks for answer. the data are many map locations info.  my mean i read them from web database by web service and show locations in map by markers and info windows. may markers count be 200. how can retrieve these 200 data from web quickly?

Comment: Use json for encoding the data from the server side and decode it at the client side. Using JSON, you can efficiently compress data to make it travel faster.

Comment: Ok. how to compress data?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Encode it in json format. Just google it and you will find it.

Answer (score -1):

You question is not really answerable in it's form. "How do I do SOMETHING quickly" in programming boils down to:

> 1. Do SOMETHING.
> 2. Do SOMETHING correctly so it's (relatively) bug free.
> 3. Profile and optimize SOMETHING until it's performing to your speed requirements.

As for this comment (sorry, can't reply to comments yet so posting it here)

> Since you're working on Android Ajax is the only way to get data to your app. - MACMAN

That's just wrong. The fact that you're working with Android has ZERO effect on what server-side technology you use. I have no idea where this person got that notion.

Comment: thanks for answer. but my mean totally :  i have an android app that want to read data from web database(data are 1000000 map lat & long). how can i do this? is that clear? should i write web service that get me json data and later convert these json to andriod data? i look for fastest way reading data from web database of course by security. is that clear? just this.thanks...

Comment: There are many ways to read data from a web service, so there isn't one right answer to this question. Google around for "JSON web service" if you're looking to use JSON. Basically you have a web service that returns JSON in response to a request. Then you have your Android app that makes requests to the service and reads the JSON.